# switching mongodb on request auth issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, coffeescript, mongoose

i am developing a multitenant app in node that switches db based on the request. 
i am using `mongoose` to create the connection to the mongo deployment where i have 3 dbs.

all my code is written in coffeescript.

here is how i create the initial connection:
conn = `mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://<user>:<pwd>@<host>:<port>,<host>:<port>/main?replicaSet=set-xxxxxxxxxx');`

here the code in the request

```
db      = conn.useDb('demo')
myModel = db.model('mymodel')

for obj in objects
  o = new settingModel(obj)
  o.save (err, obj) ->
    console.log 'err is', err if err
```

i can switch db and query the db but when i try to write to it i get a:

```
errmsg: 'not authorized on demo to execute command { insert: "settings", writeConcern: { w: 1 }...
```

how can i solve this issue? the databases are all hosted on compose.io

Comment: have you tried to login against `/admin`, then switch databases?  Also, is the same user used for each database, if not you will need to create a new connection.

Comment: You don't have privileges to insert on the `demo` database. Check your users privileges and verify you can insert. This will be easiest to do in the mongo shell.